# There isn't compile error, error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" occur in the main function's return 0

Tags: c, return, program-entry-point

Recently, I started learning C language because I was interested in it.
I was solving the problem in the textbook I was learning.
I was working on a project to create a program that stores book information (titles, authors, publishers) and allows them to be found through search.
When I run the program, run mode 1(I entered aaa for everything.) and then run mode 3, an error such as the title occurs.
"Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" message was output in the return 0; row of the main function.
The working environment was the latest version of m2 MacBook Air Xcode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// base
int str_length(char *pstr);
int str_copy(char *pstr_c, char *pstr_v);
int str_compare(char *pstr_a, char *pstr_b);
int str_add(char *pstr, char *pstr_add);

// program
int book_add(char (*pbook)[4][100], int row);
int book_search(char (*pbook)[4][100], int row);

int main() {
    char book[100][4][100];
    int ans, row = 0, end = 0;
    
    while (1) {
        printf("Choose the mode (Add 1, search 2, end 3) : ");
        scanf("%d", &ans);
        switch (ans) {
            case 1 :
                book_add(book, 100);
                row++;
                break;
            case 2 :
                book_search(book, 100);
                break;
            case 3 :
                end = 1;
            default :
                break;
        }
        if (end) { break; }
    }
    return 0;
}

// base
int str_length(char *pstr) {
    int i = 0;
    while (pstr[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
int str_copy(char *pstr/*문자*/, char *pstr_c/*복사 문자*/) {
    while (*pstr_c) {
        *pstr = *pstr_c;
        pstr_c++;
        pstr++;
    }
    *pstr = '\0';
    return 1;
}
int str_compare(char *pstr_a, char *pstr_b) {
    while (*pstr_a) {
        if (*pstr_a != *pstr_b) { return 0; }
        pstr_a++;
        pstr_b++;
    }
    if (*pstr_b != 0) { return 0; }
    return 1;
}
int str_add(char *pstr /*문자*/, char *pstr_add /*더할 문자*/) {
    while (*pstr) {
        pstr++;
    }
    while (*pstr_add) {
        *pstr = *pstr_add;
        pstr++;
        pstr_add++;
    }
    *pstr = '\0';
    return 1;
}
int str_clear(char *pstr, int row) {
    while (row) {
        *pstr = '\0';
        pstr++;
        row--;
    }
    return 1;
}

// program
int book_add(char (*pbook)[4][100], int row) {
    printf("Title : ");
    scanf("%s", &pbook[row][0][0]);
    printf("Auther : ");
    scanf("%s", &pbook[row][1][0]);
    printf("Publisher : ");
    scanf("%s", &pbook[row][2][0]);
    str_copy(&pbook[row][3][0], "available");
    return 1;
}
int book_search(char (*pbook)[4][100], int row){
/*I didn't make it yet*/
    return 1;
}
```

There seems to be a difference between the pre-compilation intention and the post-compilation result.
Now that we have entered various c languages, we have not been able to find the solution we want due to a lack of knowledge of the assembly language.

Comment: `book_add(book, 100);` This causes an out-of-bounds access on your `book` array when you use the `100` as the index: `scanf("%s", &pbook[row][0][0]);`There is no `book[100]`in your array. Valid index range only goes from `0´ to `99`.

Comment: oh, What a simple mistake! What caused the error only at the time of executing return0;?

Comment: Accessing an array out of bounds invokes undefined behaviour. Basically, anything could happen. You could write into variables next to that array affecting your program logic or you might get a segmentation fault, or it may look just as if everything worked.
Such an error generally is a runtime error. The compiler will not detect it jand you will only be hit if you execute your program.

Comment: Avoid declaring large arrays such as `char book[100][4][100];` locally on the stack. Adding lots of variables like that will build up towards a stack overflow, which are a pain to track down.